# Etymology: "main" meaning sea or ocean

Tags: etymology, poetry

In Kipling's "[The Land](http://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/poems_land.htm)" he writes:

> Then did robbers enter Britain from across the Northern main
>
> And our Lower River-field was won by Ogier the Dane.

Here "main" seems to mean sea, i.e. the North Sea.

This seems to me to allude to the Spanish Main, but from what I can find that phrase actually refers to the mainland, not the sea.

The OED (1st ed) has "4. Said of a considerable, uninterrupted strech of land or water" [(link)](https://archive.org/stream/oed6barch#page/48/mode/2up/search/main%20sea) but the examples given mostly seem to be land.

Webster's 1913 has "main, n. 3 ... the high sea; the ocean" ([link](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=main&use1913=on&use1828=on)), but again the examples seem mostly to be of land, including "the main of Spain" to mean mainland.

etymonline [doesn't have this usage of "main"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=main&allowed_in_frame=0)

What is the etymology of this usage? Is it a corruption from "Spanish Main" coming to mean sea instead of "mainland"?

Comment: OED says it's *short for main **sea** noun.; the open sea. Now chiefly poetical.* In that context, adjectival ***main*** is defined as *of a material object, an animal, etc.: of **great size or bulk**. (Sometimes connoting strength, resisting power, or the like.)* So yes - it's effectively the same usage as ***mainland***.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia entry on *Spanish Main*, (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Main) it refers to the historical Spanish 'mainland' of the north and south Americas.

Comment: [*Sailing, sailing, over the bounding main ...*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sailing,_Sailing)

Answer (score 8):

OED3 has sense 5:

> **5. a.** Short for **main sea** *n.;* the open sea. Now chiefly *poet.*
>
> > 1579   T. North *tr.* Plutarch *Liues* 472   The winde stoode full against them comming from the mayne [Fr. *le uent se tourna du costé de la pleine mer*].

The meaning of *main* and *main sea* is made clear in the French translation *pleine mer,* but it's not clear where that translation is actually from. Although *main* meaning "sea" is still in use, albeit poetical, *main sea* is marked as obsolete, with the last citation from 1876:

> 1876   A. C. Swinburne *Erechtheus* 1699   Who shall meet The wind's whole soul and might of the main sea Full in the face of battle.

Comment: But how did "mayne" come to mean sea? Is it from "Spanish Main"?

Comment: No, I believe *main* there has its normal meaning (or at least a sense closely related to it) of "principal, major, large".

Comment: Please excuse my lateness… Google brought me here because the difference between English *High* and US American *Main Streets* brought up *Spanish Main*. My French wasn’t good enough but Andrew’s aside contrasted archaic English Plutarch’s *the mayne* with French Plutarch’s translation *pleine mer* as, Google says, *high waters*.
Are they too far apart to matter or is *high waters* really English *high seas*, rather than anything like *mighty waves*?

I thought *Main Street* just the most important route in town, unlike the contrast of British local *by*-ways and national *high*-ways. More…

Comment: More… 
Now, doesn’t French *high waters* reconcile them; more strongly since the birth of the *Spanish Main* and *US Main Streets*  weren't too far apart?

Then, Swinburne and Erechtheus’ *whole soul and might of the main sea* in particular stirs something about strength of arm and skill of hand; French hand, that is.

Comment: I believe "Spanish Main" is just from "main" meaning sea. I have always taken "Spanish main" to mean the sea chiefly frequented and controlled by the Spanish, i.e. largely the Carribean and the South American approaches.